# ForLoop to create a dataset with branched data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to create a dataset with this structure [image]

It's like creating a hierarchical structure dataset. The final dataset would have 100 x 2 x 3 x 25 = 15,000 rows of data. I'm using Python with Pandas
(There are 100 values for variables no.1. In each value of variable no.1, there will be 2 variables from variable no.2. And in each value of variable no.2, there will be 3 variables from variable no.3, and so on)

I have tried to use ForLoop for Variable No.4, but I can't figure out how to make higher level Variable fill in the dataset alternately.

```
variable4= range(0,25)

for i in range (0,25):
    dataset.iloc[i,4] = variable4[i]
    dataset.iloc[i,3] = 'Var3value'
```

Please give me some advice on how to make this type of structure.

P/s: using parallel computing for faster computational time is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and then call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a = range(100)
b = list('ab')
c = list('ABC')
d = list(range(100, 125))

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([a,b,c,d], names=list('xyuz'))

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':range(15000)}, index=mux)
print (df)
              col
x  y u z         
0  a A 100      0
       101      1
       102      2
       103      3
       104      4
       105      5
       106      6
...
...
```

Comment: a really neat solution for this!
I have one question: How can I turn the Index into the row data, with each variable in one column?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Simply call `df = df.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

You can brute force this using nested for loops. There are more efficient ways to do this but for the data size this should be fine.

```
df = of.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(5):
            for l in range(10):
                df.append([i, j, k, l], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

You can use itertools.product() if you want to omit the for loops. This makes it more efficient. If you want to make the data frame with one step. Create a 2d list/array and the. Generate the dataframe.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I agree to for this small dataset, but for a bigger dataset, I read that I should perform the operation on the whole dataset at once, not row by row. That idea just stuck in my head and I can't find a way to do it